# How to execute a function if nothing happens in some seconds or else continue

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a program to move the mouse according to keyboard keys pressed

for example pressing 'f' then 'g' takes the mouse to right or 'g' to 'i' takes it 3 steps to right and one up, each step is 70 pixels (the program is specifically for my screen and keyboard) but if I press 'w' then 'x' it goes 2 steps down but then I have no way to continue going down,

previously I had it work like only with surrounding keys like 'd' then 'f' but pressing after than 'u' then 'j' goes down good because it defaults to it again,

the new method doesn't work like that and I can't figure out a way to solve it except that if some seconds pass without pressing anything it goes back to defaults (reading again) so if I press 'e' 'b' and then lets say 3 seconds pass without pressing anything it waits like new, or if that 3 second waiting is broken (by pressing a key) it continues from where it left.

here's my code (I didn't know how to do the final one about waiting and google didn't help (maybe I don't know what to search correctly):

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.mouse import Controller

offset_dictionary = {............}

mouse = Controller()
prev = ""
curr = ""

def on_release(key):
    global prev, curr
    if no key is pressed in 3 seconds: # here is my kind pseudo code for the idea
        prev = curr = ""
        return None:
    if key == keyboard.Key.space or type(key) is not keyboard.KeyCode:
        return False
    if prev == "":
        prev = key.char
        return None
    curr = key.char
    try:
        offset = offset_dictionary[prev][curr]
    except KeyError:
        prev = curr
        return None
    offset = offset[0] * 70, offset[1] * 70
    mouse.move(offset[0], offset[1])
    prev = curr


with keyboard.Listener(
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

offset_dictionary is a very very big dictionary for each key on the keyboard having a dictionary inside it holding a tuple for the offset

here is a small example

```
offset_dictionary = {
"`":{"`":(0,0),
    "1":(1,0),
    "2":(2,0),
    "3":(3,0),
```

now my idea is something like a timer starts and if a key is pressed, the timer stops and the program contiunes and the the timer restarts, else if no key is pressed until the timer is over it goes back to default waiting for new keys

Comment: IMO your idea is the way to go, you need some kind of timer object. Might be this will be helpful https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects

Comment: @CrowbarKZ I read about that but I didn't know how to implement it, how can I start the timer and if I press something it stops?

Comment: Checkout their example. `t = Timer(30.0, hello); t.start()` - start the timer. `t.cancel(); t.start();` - restart it and resent back to 30 secs. @Anton-Kahwaji